# Aerospike Version, any other major upgrades before 3.13.x necessary?

Tags: aerospike

Our Enterprise AS cluster is on v 3.7.3, do we need to upgrade to any of the versions before 3.13.x or can we directly upgrade to the major 3.13.x version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, shouldn't be a problem to upgrade from 3.7 to 3.13.

Note: As an Enterprise user you have access to our 24 hr support team at [support.aerospike.com](http://support.aerospike.com).

Comment: For your reading pleasure: https://www.aerospike.com/docs/operations/upgrade/aerospike  but as an enterprise user, do open a support ticket.